# Pull objects out of List<T> by multiple Id's at once?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list

I have a `List<Group>` where `Group` is:

```
class Group
{
  string Id,
  string Name
}
```

I have a `List<string>` which contains a list of Id's

I want to pull all the `Group` objects out of the `List<Group>` which have an Id in the `List<string>`

Something like `var groups = groupList.Where(x => x.Id == "id")` except for multiple Id's at once.

Comment: Make id list a `HashSet<T>` for better performance.

Comment: Thanks... it's only going to contain at most 30 or so objects, but that's something to keep in mind for sure. Thanks.

Comment: would it make sense to get a feel of which would be bigger? grouplist or id list? I guess that would help reduce iterations, by using grouplist.where or idlist.select?

Comment: Strike the last comment, didnt realize hashset lookup is O(1).

Comment: @SrikanthVenugopalan: But choosing which collection is larger still makes sense: intersection will be more efficient if convert to hashset larger, and iterate over smaller.

Comment: @abatishchev- I agree, instinctively I am usually tempted to do this analysis before choosing which collection to 'LINQ' upon. You are right in pointing out that this would probably make sense to choose which could be the Hashset. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
List<string> ids = GetTheIDs();

var groups = groupList.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id));
```

That being said, this will be inefficient for large numbers of IDs.  If you have many ID values, you may want to place them in a `HashSet<T>` instead of a `List<T>`, as the `Contains()` call will be O(1) instead of O(n) in that case.

Answer (score 2):

```
var groups = groupList.Where(x => listOfStrings.Contains(x.Id));
```

Where `listOfStrings` is your "I have a `List<string>` which contains a list of Id's".

Answer (score 1):

```
var groups = groupList.Where(x => stringList.Contains(x.Id));
```